# How to set default value in comboBox javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to set a default value for a `ComboBox` from an `ObservableArrayList`, I am trying to set the first value in my `ArrayList` as a default value.

```
List = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arrayList);
comboBox.setItems(List);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Answer (score 25):

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(index);
```

where `index` is the [integer position](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-int-) of the item to select in the selection model, or a [value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-T-) from and of the same type as the arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

I was just looking for a way to leave it in the same way I had started with, in my case with an introductory text